# Need a good Visual Studio extensibility tutorial

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Does anyone know of any good tutorials on starting to write MS Visual Studio 2015 Extensions?  I have been trying to find documentation or tutorials on the subject but the Microsoft Developer Network is not complete or well structured and doesn't really qualify as a "Tutorial" in my opinion.  I haven't found much else out there but a few tutorials on how to do one specific thing not a tutorial on the concepts and ideas in general. Does anyone have any links to good tutorials on this subject? I would really appreciate it.  
Thanks and happy programming!

Comment: See https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/resources.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost all resources about Visual Studio Extensibility on my web site: http://visualstudioextensibility.com/. Specially see the [LearnVSXNow series](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages/).